# Zend Framework: How to add multilingue form element zf 1.12

Tags: forms, zend-framework, frameworks, element

I want to add Multilinge Form element  with ZF 1.12.
Like This :

```
<input type="text" name="content[fr][title]"  />

<input type="text" name="content[en][title]"  />
```

How can I implement it as simply as possible? Thanks

Comment: <input type="text" name="content[fr][title]"  />

Comment: And what is the problem? `$form = new Zend_Form(); $form->addElement($form->createElement('text', 'content[fr][title]')); $form->addElement($form->createElement('text', 'content[en][title]')); echo $form;`